# Indexing between cells, structs & matrices - loops and assigning data

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, import, indexing

As the title suggests, this is likely an indexing problem, but possibly also about incompatibilities. I have sets of data, all in mixed object types; matrices, structs, double, char, cell.
What I want to achieve is quite simple: I have a function from the matlab community that allows me to extract stock price data from Yahoo. This function looks like this:

```
market_data = hist_stock_data('start_date','end_date','name_of_stock')
```

This function return a struct with 8 field - 1 char, 1 cell and 6 doubles, and I have successfully implemented it for one single stock - but I need more!
I have the names of the stocks saved in a separate file, currently as a cell, each stock in a row of its own, appearing as a string if called upon, e.g 'ADS.DE'   (Adidas stock name). These strings have either 6 or 7 characters i.e are not uniform. I have the stocks saved at text too, so maybe there's an alternative to a cell? Snipet from Matlab:

```
stock_names = 

'ADS.DE'
'ALV.DE'
'BAS.DE'
'BAYN.DE'
'BEI.DE'
'BMW.DE'
```

What I would like to do is create my own function, simply with a for-loop or something similar, to carry out the 'hist_stock_data' function above for each of the stocks in my list, and to then extract from each of the corresponding structs that are returned, a select few of the fields (including potentially one of each of the kinds, char, cell and double).

Ideally I would have a matrix at the end, that has just one column for each of the stocks in my list.

I know I can extract them from the structs by doing for example:

```
struct.price   % the stock price field of a given struct
```

but I also have problems inserting this into another matrix or somewhere else where I can do further mathematical analysis on it (functions: cov(), corr(), eig() and so on).

I would be grateful for any help and suggestions - please let me know if I can provide more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `hist_stock_data` can't already take a cell array of stock names and return a corresponding struct array (worth checking), It's as simple as:

```
for ii=1:numel(stock_names)
    market_data(ii) = hist_stock_data(start_date, end_date, stock_names{ii});
end
```

Then you can extract fields from the struct array into vectors with concatenation:

```
vector_data = [market_data.scalar_field];

matrix_data = [market_data.column_vector_field];   % or,
matrix_data = vertcat(market_data.row_vector_field]);

cell_data = {market_data.nonscalar_field};
```

which might be useful for certain things:

```
prices = {market_data.price};  % assuming price is a vector
avgprices = cellfun(@mean, prices);
```

Alternatively, instead of extracting each field individually, you might prefer to pass the struct array to `struct2cell`, then just use `cell2mat` or `cellfun` to do things with individual rows of the resulting cell array.

Note that the cell arrays still don't mind if the data size for each stock differs - dealing with this in the analysis may be non-trivial since the correct approach (pool, truncate, zero-pad, interpolate, etc.) depends on the data and what exactly you're doing with it.

Comment: Well I'll be jibbered - The first part at least worked like a charm!

I now have a struct with the returned 8 variables according to each stock in their own field. (In this case a 1x30 struct).

I can't adapt the second part of your answer though - I get the message that `horzcat` can't be used as the mmatrices are not consistent. I have checked several and they are all [1x23]. Do I need to predefine your 'price' variable?

The function `hist_stock_data` can't take a cell array, unfortunately.

Comment: @DexterMorgan Ah, somehow I assumed `price` was a scalar - `vertcat(market_data.price)` might be more appropriate, but if the data's inconsistent you may need to fall back to cell arrays - I've generalised my answer a bit, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, @Notlikethat! I have managed to get the price fields out of the struct and into one cell, then into matrix form with `cell2mat`. To get that far I had to manually adjust the lengths of the price fields to all be even (so 'numel(market_data.price)' was constant), so that any form of concatenation would work. This is something that it a little complicated too as I want to pad them out with the mean, for example. **Any ideas?**

Once I can get this part automated, I think I've got it!
I've only been programming using matlab for a week in total, so it's taking me ages!